# In R, how to analyze Strip-Plot Design when there are three factors?

Tags: experiment-design, research-design, split-plot

I have one dataset like below

```r
dataA= structure(list(sowing_date= c("Early", "Early", "Early", 
                                      "Early", "Early", "Early", 
                                      "Early", "Early", "Early", 
                                      "Early", "Early", "Early", 
                                      "Late", "Late", "Late", 
                                      "Late", "Late", "Late", 
                                      "Late", "Late", "Late", 
                                      "Late", "Late", "Late"), 
                      herbicide= c("H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", 
                                    "H0", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
                                    "H1", "H1", "H0", "H0", "H0", 
                                    "H0", "H0", "H0", "H1", "H1",
                                    "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1"), 
                      nitrogen= c("N0", "N0", "N0", "N1", "N1", 
                                   "N1", "N0", "N0", "N0", "N1", 
                                   "N1", "N1", "N0", "N0", "N0", 
                                   "N1", "N1", "N1", "N0", "N0", 
                                   "N0", "N1", "N1", "N1"), 
                      Block= c("Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", 
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", 
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", 
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", 
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", 
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", 
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3",
                               "Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3"), 
                      Yield= c(30, 27, 25, 40, 41, 42, 37, 38, 
                               40, 48, 47, 46, 25, 27, 26, 41, 
                               41, 42,38, 39, 42, 57, 59, 60)), 
                 class= "data.frame", 
                 row.names= c(NA, -24L))

   sowing_date herbicide nitrogen   Block Yield
1        Early        H0       N0 Block 1    30
2        Early        H0       N0 Block 2    27
3        Early        H0       N0 Block 3    25
4        Early        H0       N1 Block 1    40
5        Early        H0       N1 Block 2    41
6        Early        H0       N1 Block 3    42
7        Early        H1       N0 Block 1    37
8        Early        H1       N0 Block 2    38
9        Early        H1       N0 Block 3    40
10       Early        H1       N1 Block 1    48
11       Early        H1       N1 Block 2    47
12       Early        H1       N1 Block 3    46
13        Late        H0       N0 Block 1    25
14        Late        H0       N0 Block 2    27
15        Late        H0       N0 Block 3    26
16        Late        H0       N1 Block 1    41
17        Late        H0       N1 Block 2    41
18        Late        H0       N1 Block 3    42
19        Late        H1       N0 Block 1    38
20        Late        H1       N0 Block 2    39
21        Late        H1       N0 Block 3    42
22        Late        H1       N1 Block 1    57
23        Late        H1       N1 Block 2    59
24        Late        H1       N1 Block 3    60
```

Now, my experimental design is strip-plot design, and the corresponding R code is below

```r
library(agricolae)
model = with(dataA, strip.plot(BLOCK=Block, COL=herbicide, 
                               ROW=sowing_date, Yield))
```

However, this model is when there are only two factors like below layout

[image]

I have three factors; sowing_date, herbicide and nitrogen. I'd like to randomize nitrogen within herbicide and sowing_date like below layout.

[image]

Could you let me know how to analyze strip-plot design when there are three factors? Maybe, I can use split-split plot design, but the layout is designed as strip-plot, I think I want to use the model for strip-plot.

Simply, I added nitrogen in the model, but it doesn't work

```r
model= with(dataA, strip.plot(BLOCK=Block,COL=herbicide, 
                        ROW=sowing_date, nitrogen, Yield))

    Error in strip.plot(BLOCK = Block, COL = herbicide, 
             ROW = sowing_date,  : 
    unused argument (Yield)
```

Could you answer my questions?